# error on installing curl on windows 10

Tags: curl

Trying to install curl on windows 10.
I have just downloaded curl  from the following link http://winampplugins.co.uk/curl/ and unzipped it in "C:\curl" and run the following commands:

```
cd "c:\curl"
```

and then

```
"curl –X GET –u <username> 'https://<account>.cloudant.com'
```

I am having the following message after providing my password:

```
Enter host password for user 'tottihope':
```

curl: (1) Protocol "'https" not supported or disabled in libcurl
Any suggestions on how to get enable libcurl on windows

kindest regards

Comment: Thanks. I have just followed your link and went into the bin. Here is the result :

 Directory of C:\curl

2015-12-15  12:52 PM    <DIR>          .
2015-12-15  12:52 PM    <DIR>          ..
2015-12-02  07:03 AM           256,338 curl-ca-bundle.crt
2015-12-02  07:03 AM         1,977,856 curl.exe
2015-12-02  07:03 AM           565,248 libcurl.dll
               3 File(s)      2,799,442 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  335,633,784,832 bytes free

Comment: but when I run cd "C:\curl" and then curl.exe I am prompted to check the manual "curl --help" ,"curl --manual" and so on

Comment: I am now faced with a new issue after passing my parameters : C:\Users\totti>curl -X GET -u <username> 'https://<account>.cloudant.com'
Enter host password for user 'tottihope':
curl: (1) Protocol "'https" not supported or disabled in libcurl

Comment: It is all in the error message: `"'https"`. Pay attention to the single `'`, remove that from the command line, then curl will no longer complain about `'https` and will use `https`

Comment: ok I will give this a go

Comment: @Marged thanks very much. it worked like a charm.

Comment: You are welcome. The only problem is that by editing your original question and putting your secondary problem into it my answer does no longer match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a misunderstand here. The file you mentioned is containing the sourcecode of curl. So you can't run it directly, you first would have to compile it.

While compiling on your own might have advantages what you are probably searching for is a precompiled binary. These binaries are provided for several platforms and are linked further down the download page.

For Windows you will find these:

[image: CURL for Windows download links]

Current versions are highlighted in yellow. Depending on your requirements you can choose from a plethora of archives.
Probably a [safe bet](https://bintray.com/artifact/download/vszakats/generic/curl-7.46.0-win32-mingw.7z) with maximum functionality and least dependencies is the Win32 Generic binary which includes SSL and SSH.